# Where does MQ Explorer keeps logs of activities of everything done via MQ Explorer?

Tags: ibm-mq

We currently use MQ Explorer to manage a WebSphere MQ V7 on Z/OS.
Few days ago I deleted a queue by mistake.
Later I wanted to go back in history and look some logs to see when it exactly happened.
My question is, where does MQ Explorer logs all activities that takes place via MQ Explorer?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

MQ Explorer does not have such a log. If you want an audit trail of things done to your queue manager you should enable command events on the queue manager, that way you'll have an audit trail regardless of the tool used to do the deed.

Command events are enabled using `ALTER QMGR CMDEV(ENABLED)` or if you prefer not to clutter the audit trail with Display commands, use `ALTER QMGR CMDEV(NODISPLAY)`.

You may also want to consider configuration events, which provide a snapshot of a object before and after any change. For example in your example where a queue is deleted, the configuration event will contain a snapshot of what the queue looked like before it was deleted, allowing that information to be used to reinstate the queue as it was.

Read more:-

- [Command Events](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q036520_.htm)
- [Command Event reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.doc/q049820_.htm)
- [Configuration Events](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q036480_.htm)
- [Create object Event reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.doc/q049830_.htm)
- [Change object Event reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.doc/q049690_.htm)
- [Delete object Event reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.doc/q049860_.htm)

Comment: A new user wrote an answer that is more of a comment and will probably get removed.   "From which log/log location I can can see this event log."  I noticed understandably that the links in your 2014 answer are no  longer valid.